# PHP connectivity with MS SQL using odbc_connect

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, sqlsrv

I am working on a PHP project where I have to create an API to fetch data from client's MS SQL server. I am doing it as-

```
$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=$server_ip;Database=$databse;", $username, $password);
```

Its working on my localhost(might be because I have SQL Server install on my system, but not sure). But does not work on hosting server. It gives error-

```
[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server Native Client 10.0' : file not found
```

I have even tried -

```
$serverName = $server_ip;
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>$database, "UID"=>$username, "PWD"=>$password);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

$conn does not return anything.
```

Is there any other alternative?

I have even got odbc driver install.

Comment: What's your exact request? Do you want a database extension that doesn't require installing SQL Server Native Client? What are your system specs? (If I recall correctly, SQLSRV requires PHP/7 to work on Unix).

Comment: I have PHP Version 5.6.30 on Linux server. Is there any database extension that doesn't require installing SQL Server Native Client? Might be helpful!

Comment: Maybe good old [mssql extension](http://php.net/mssql), but I can't tell you exactly (I've never used it). In any case, it isn't an alternative with a lot of future (it's gone in PHP/7).

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative (extension) called php-sybase. I am using it successfully to connect to various (versions) MSSQL databases with different php versions, to mention just: 5.6 and 7.0.